# Excel unsorts cells when shifting right

Tags: excel, vba

Why do the cells unsort when i use the following code?

```
Dim numOfRow As Integer
numOfRows = Worksheets("result").Cells(Rows.Count, "s").End(xlUp).Row

Range("S10:V" & CStr(numOfRows)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert shift:=xlToRight
```

Cell content before shifting: 236259
 After shifting right: 324359
(There are 3400 cells so they get mixed up randomly but why? After line 242 they were shifted correctly and the cell contents are like they should.)

Comment: I have a column with numbers in it. Then i want to shift them right and insert a column at the column position of the shifted column. Yes there is more code but i think its no really relevant.

Comment: Yes. I debugged through it step to step and see that the numbers are in the right order in the column before shifting and after the shifting process they are randomly mixed up. (Thanks for help pnuts. :) )

Comment: Oh my god. I am so dumb. I found the solution.
I oversighted the following code:
<code>Rows("21:241").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("H21"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Range("H21").Select</code>

Comment: It is better if you post the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god. I am so dumb. I found the solution. I oversighted the following code:

`Rows("21:241").Select Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("H21"), Order1:=xlAscending, _ Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _ DataOption1:=xlSortNormal Range("H21").Select`